# Pandas preprocessing data and labelling

Tags: python, pandas

I want to divide my data into labels in that the first 6 columns determine the 7th column now I have selected the first 6 columns which is working perfectly

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix

#Assign column names to the dataset
names=['buying', 'maint', 'doors', 'persons', 'lug_boot','safety', 'class']

# load the dataset in csv format into the pandas dataframe
cardata= pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\user\Downloads\car.data', names=names)

X = cardata.iloc[:, 0:6]
```

The above code is working perfectly and when I run

```
print(X.head())
```

[image]

it prints the first  6 columns with exemption of the last column which is supposed to be predicted.
But this code below seems not to work as it outputs a similar behaviour to the one above

```
y = cardata.select_dtypes(include=[object])
print(y.head())
```

please help I need to assign the variable `y` to only the last column that is the seventh column

The output is the same which is not the case , I need when I run `print(y.head())` it only prints the last column

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
X,y = cardata.iloc[:,:-1],cardata.iloc[:,-1]
```

This selects all rows and separates `X` and `y` based on the last column (index = `-1`). This should get you the result you are looking for